# Truffle migration error on Rospten Infura

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts, truffle

Trying to deploy a smart contract with:

```
$ truffle migrate --network ropsten
```

**But I got this error:**

```
/home/user/Documentos/testcontract/node_modules/eth-block-tracker/src/polling.js:51
        const newErr = new Error(`PollingBlockTracker - encountered an error while attempting to update latest block:\n${err.stack}`)
                       ^
Error: PollingBlockTracker - encountered an error while attempting to update latest block:
undefined
    at PollingBlockTracker._performSync (/home/user/Documentos/testcontract/node_modules/eth-block-tracker/src/polling.js:51:24)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

**My truffle-config.js:**

```
networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",     // Localhost (default: none)
      port: 8545,            // Standard Ethereum port (default: none)
      network_id: "*",       // Any network (default: none)
    },
    ropsten: {
      provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(mnemonicPhras, 'https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/1a470cedbc0d423592811o8bd1aa3e33'),
      network_id: 3,       // Ropsten's id
      gas: 5500000,        // Ropsten has a lower block limit than mainnet
      confirmations: 2,    // # of confs to wait between deployments. (default: 0)
      timeoutBlocks: 200,  // # of blocks before a deployment times out  (minimum/default: 50)
      skipDryRun: true     // Skip dry run before migrations? (default: false for public nets )
    },}
  }
```

With ganache works perfectly, but I need try whit this testnet...

Comment: Try replacing 'https' in the provider URL with 'wss'. Source: https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/3357

Comment: @MuhtasimUlfatTanmoy still not working, I get: abortHandshake(this, req, `Unexpected server response: ${res.statusCode}`);

Comment: Can you please share the statusCode?

Answer (score -1):

I also got the same error and tried to use `ws` instead of `https` endpoint and got the following issue.

`Error: Unexpected server response: 401.`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).